# Telegram bot for arXiv

Tags: telegram-bot

I was wondering if there exists any Telegram bot that sends me arXiv articles **everyday**?

I looked up the internet but I couldn't find. I need it since it's basically hard to browse arXiv everyday and read new articles. I am not sure if here is the best place to ask this question. So sorry if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are some Telegram bots for arXiv. The one candidate for what you're looking for is [@dailyarXiv_bot](https://telegram.me/dailyarxiv_bot) that sends you submitted articles everyday. Another famous option is [@ArXivBot](https://github.com/carlosparaciari/ArXivBot). Another bot that I've just recently seen is [arXiv_kitten](https://github.com/Noxbru/arXiv_Kitten).

Comment: None of them seem to be operative in Telegram as of today.